# Android button returns as null

Tags: java, android

I have a project that contains multiple fragments and I use a bottom navigation to switch between them. In my last fragment I am trying to have a button that changes its text based on the input on the previous fragment. I am using a bundle to transfer the data, which works fine, but when I try to set the button's text to the transferred input, I get a null pointer. I have debugged and found out that for whatever reason, Android Studio is setting the button to null even with proper declarations. I'm still fairly new to Android so any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class Result extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private Button drugButton;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Result() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static Result newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Result fragment = new Result();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup fragment_container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,fragment_container,false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    drugButton = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.drugButt);
    System.out.println(drugButton);
    if(args != null)
    {
        String drug = args.getString("resultKey");
        drugButton.setText(drug);
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, fragment_container, false);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

This is my error message.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.alurk.marnpp, PID: 8735
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.alurk.marnpp.Result$override.onCreateView(Result.java:57)
    at com.example.alurk.marnpp.Result$override.access$dispatch(Unknown Source:116)
    at com.example.alurk.marnpp.Result.onCreateView(Unknown Source:21)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're returning different view in `onCreateView` with this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup fragment_container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,fragment_container,false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    drugButton = (Button) view2.findViewById(R.id.drugButt);
    System.out.println(drugButton);
    if(args != null)
    {
        String drug = args.getString("resultKey");
        drugButton.setText(drug);
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, fragment_container, false);
}
```

You should do something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup fragment_container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,fragment_container,false);


        ...

        return view2;

}
```

---

The error is happened because you're binding the Button in `onCreateView` with the view from:

```
View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,fragment_container,false);
```

But then you're giving different view in the end of the method with:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, fragment_container, false);
```

Comment: When i use return view2 it puts up a copy of my second fragment, when I have the current return statement it shows the fragment correctly.

Comment: That's mean the correct layout is the second one, which is `fragment_result` layout.

Comment: @ALurkingBear in which layout exist your button? fragment_result  or fragment_search?

Comment: So, change the `View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search,fragment_container,false);` to `View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result,fragment_container,false);`

Comment: @ALurkingBear: The steps are:
1. get the layout  
2. Inflate the layout as a View  
3. Get the Button as the child of the View  
4. Set the value to the button  
5. Give the View as the returned value needed by the onCreateView method.

Comment: Ah, I see what happened. When I created the fragment_result it did not include the inflate line. I copied that line from my fragment_search but forgot to swap the code. Everything works as intended now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, fragment_container, false);
```

to

```
    return view2;
```

I think that's because you don't return the wrong layout, you inflate other layout than you return

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

First things first, decide which layout you want to inflate:

`R.layout.fragment_search` or `R.layout.fragment_result`

The later one seems much obvious.

Next, use `onViewCreated()` by overriding it. This method brings the view that was inflated in your `onCreateView()`. So your code looks much clear than your current code:

```
// best place to fetch arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

// best place to inflate layout that you want to be displayed in Fragment
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflate(R.layout.fragment_result,fragment_container,false);
}

// best place to use the View that was inflated in onCreateView()
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    drugButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.drugButt);
}
```